# Is there a SQL code for cumulative count of SaaS customer over months?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with:
ID (id client), date_start (subscription of SaaS), date_end (could be a date value or be NULL).

So I need a cumulative count of active clients month by month.

any idea on how to write that in Postgres and achieve this result? [image]

Starting from this, but I don't know how to proceed

```
select 
date_trunc('month', c.date_start)::date,
count(*) 
from customer
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you able to write a query to get the first three columns? Then you'd just have to add a cumulative sum (`SUM OVER`).

Comment: Why do both 5 (jan) and 4 (feb) count in February? I'd say either count them always in the month they get added or always in the following month. But you count 5 in the following month and 4 in the month they are added. Why? Is this a mistake or a special rule. If the latter, then please explain this rule.

Comment: Yes I was trying to write the query, I have a table with a list of customer: Id, name, date start, date end; I need to apply a count by month of date_start

Comment: Then show the query please.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in January we have 5 subscribers that pay a monthly plan, then in February, we will have the five of January (-2 lost subscribers) + 4 Feb.that will pay the monthly fee

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, but  it's not what i'm looking for; I need to recalculate month over month because it's not just a cumulative sum, as well I can have churn subscribers

Comment: why is your result for January 0 (not counting the 5 new subscribers), but in February it is 7 (counting the 4 new subscribers)?  Aside from that, your problem appears to be indeed a cumulative sum: `sum(new_subscribers - churn) over (order by month)`.

Comment: correct @PierreD I should find the way to take new_subscribers for each month + subscribers prv.month (still active). Do you know the best way how to query it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check next solution:

```
select 
    subscrubed_date,
    subscrubed_customers,
    unsubscrubed_customers,
    coalesce(subscrubed_customers, 0) - coalesce(unsubscrubed_customers, 0) cumulative
from (
    select distinct
    date_trunc('month', c.date_start)::date subscrubed_date,
    sum(1) over (order by date_trunc('month', c.date_start)) subscrubed_customers
    from customer c
    order by subscrubed_date
) subscribed
left join (
    select distinct
    date_trunc('month', c.date_end)::date unsubscrubed_date,
    sum(1) over (order by date_trunc('month', c.date_end)) unsubscrubed_customers
    from customer c
    where date_end is not null
    order by unsubscrubed_date
) unsubscribed on subscribed.subscrubed_date = unsubscribed.unsubscrubed_date;
```

[share SQL query](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=0eae749c9ee4f3c5f67097108eac5ac4&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You have a table of customers. With a start date and sometimes an end date. As you want to group by date, but there are two dates in the table, you need to split these first.

Then, you may have months where only customers came and others where only customers left. So, you'll want a full outer join of the two sets.

For a cumulative sum (also called a running total), use `SUM OVER`.

```
with came as
(
  select date_trunc('month', date_start) as month, count(*) as cnt 
  from customer
  group by date_trunc('month', date_start)
)
, went as
(
  select date_trunc('month', date_end) as month, count(*) as cnt
  from customer
  where date_end is not null
  group by date_trunc('month', date_end)
)
select
  month,
  came.cnt as cust_new,
  went.cnt as cust_gone,
  sum(came.cnt - went.cnt) over (order by month) as cust_active
from came full outer join went using (month)
order by month;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you as well! It's what I was looking for!